# Compute this Indefinite Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

A friend of mine asked me to solve this integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)dx}{x(1+x^2)}, a>0 , a\neq1. $$

but has no idea what is the answer or whether it can be solved or not. I tried pretty much everything I know but I failed so I tried using Residue calculus but got stuck in choosing the particular contour . Since there are 3 singularity points at x = 0 ,$i$ ,$-i$ , I decided to break the denominator $\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}$into partial fractions $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}$. That way I only had to deal with a singularity at 0 and $i$ seperately but I find it quite hard to navigate my way forward.

Please help and also explain the importance of the condition $a>0$ .

Comment: Just a note about your terminology, this is an improper integral, not an indefinite integral.

Comment: In fact, $a$ can be any number.

Comment: I think maybe feynman:

$$ I(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \tan^{-1} (ax) }{x(1+x^2)} dx$$

Differentiate with $a$

$$ I' = \int_{R+} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2) (1+a^2x^2)} = A \tan^{-1}(x) + \frac{B \tan^{-1}( ax)}{a}|_{bounds} = \frac{\pi}{4} (A+B)$$

For $ a \neq 0$ After this integrate with $a$:

$$I = \frac{\pi}{4} \ln(a) (A+\frac{B}{a})$$

Comment: Dunno if I made mistake or something but I am stuck T_T

Comment: Using the advice of @Buraian: let's consider 
$$J(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan (ax)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$
$$\frac{d}{da}\,J(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+(xa)^2)(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{1}{a^2}\,\frac{1}{1-(1/a)^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{(x^2+(1/a)^2)}\,-\,\frac{1}{x^2+1}\Bigr)dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{a^2-1}\Bigl(a\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d(ax)}{(ax)^2+1}\,-\,\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}\Bigr)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{a+1}$$
Given that $J(0)=0$,   $\,\,J(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(1+a)$

Comment: @Buraian@Svyatoslav It was quite awesome. Thought of Using Feynman technique didn't cross my mind. On a soft note , can it be solved uaing Residue Calculus??? Just curious

Comment: Oh right, that was a bad idea to integrate right after partial fractions. Missed that the coefficients can come in terms of the $a$. Nice on completing it

Comment: I'm not that good with CA to comment on that, but someone who is will probably answer soon. Good question tho ^^

Comment: If $a<0$ we should define the branch of $\tan^{-1}(ax)$. If we choose for $x>0$ $\tan^{-1}(ax)= -\tan^{-1}(|a|x)$ $J(a)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(1+|a|)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use Feynman's integration method, and partial fraction decomposition, you would get:
$$\frac {df(a)}{da}=\frac {\pi}{2(a+1)}$$
Here $f(a)$ is your original required integral. After that the question is quite elementary.

PS: I see the same thing has been done in the comment section. What is the protocol now? Should I delete?

Comment: Definitely not ;)

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

Integral can be evaluated via contour integration.
Because $\arctan(ax)$ has branch points and requires cut to make the integrand single-valued, it would be more convenient to integrate by part first: $$J(a)=\int_0^\infty\arctan (ax) \frac{1}{2}d\Bigl(\log\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Bigr)=-\frac{a}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+a^2x^2}\log\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{a\,dx}{1+a^2x^2}\log\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\log\frac{t^2}{a^2+t^2}$$
Integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log t}{1+t^2}=0$ (can be shown via the change $t=\frac{1}{x}$), so
$$J(a)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\log (t^2+a^2)}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\log (t+ia)}{1+t^2}dt$$
$\log (t+ia)$ is a single-valued function in the upper half of the complex plane, so we can close the contour by adding a half-circle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane. Integral along this half-circle $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$
$$J(a)=\Re\Bigl(2\pi i \frac{1}{2}Res_{t=i}\frac{\log (t+ia)}{(t+i)(t-i)}\Bigr)=\frac{\pi}{2}\Re\log(i+ia)=\frac{\pi}{2}\log(1+a)$$

Comment: Much awaited comment. Really Appreciate it